# Where is the documentation for the GeoTIFF-jai Library

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics, geospatial, geotiff

I am trying to use the GeoTIFF-jai Library to generate a geo-rectified, raster image in Java.  I have tried looking on the SourceForge site for the documentation on how to do this, but SourceForge says "Unfortunately, this project hasn't indicated the best way to get help."  Has anyone else tried using this library and been able to find any documentation on it?

If there truly is no documentation, maybe you can answer this question.  When I import the library .jar file into my Eclipse project (using right-click->Import...->Archive File) all of the .properties files import but not the .class files.  I need the GeoTIFFFactory class from org.geotiff.images.jai in order to create a new GeoTIFF image but it's not available. Any idea why the .class files are not importing?  Am I doing something wrong on the import?  Is the .jar in the wrong directory?

Any help with either of these questions is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I import the library .jar file into my Eclipse project (using 
>   right-click->Import...->Archive File) all of the .properties files 
>   import but not the .class files. Am I doing something wrong on the import?

Yes. That's not how you use third-party jars in Eclipse. The wizard you invoked is used primarily for importing archives with source code to make changes to them. Instead create Java project to hold your source code and add a dependency on the jar via Project Properties -> Java Build Path. You can also attach a source code archive in the same place (get this from project's site on SourceForge). This will let you see any available javadoc and if there is no documentation at all, you can at least step through the code.

Regarding lack of documentation, you will be more likely to get help on that project's forum rather than on stack-overflow (since the odds of you finding help on stack-overflow with a particular library is inversely proportional to that library's popularity).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It's been a while since I've used Eclipse (or Java for that matter), I guess I needed a refresher.